# Javascript - callback sql error

Tags: javascript, sql, callback

My first question here.

This code gives an SQL error, although I already got the **newID** correct from the callback.
The alert message gives me back the correct new ID (ID+1).
But when proceeding, I still get an error from the function `getNewDatabaseID(callback)`.

EDIT: the error I get is:
    function errorDB(err) {
       alert("Error processing SQLnew: " + err);
    }

EDIT2: While this works just fine:
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO tabel (_id, datum, food, cal) VALUES (2223, date("now"), "taart", 3200)');

```
function saveFoodToDatabase(dag, typeFood, calories) {
    db.transaction(saveFoodDB, errorDB, successDB);
    function saveFoodDB(tx) {
        getNewDatabaseID(function callback(_newID) {
            var newID = _newID;
            alert(dag + ' ' + newID);
            tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO tabel (_id, datum, food, cal) VALUES ('
                + newID + ' , date("now" , "-' + dag + ' days"), "'
                + typeFood + '" , ' + calories + ')');
        });
    }
    function errorDB(err) {
        alert("Error processing SQLsave: " + err);
    }
    function successDB() {
        $.mobile.changePage("#dayPage");
    }
}

function getNewDatabaseID(callback) {
    db.transaction(getMaxIDDB, errorDB);
    function getMaxIDDB(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('SELECT _id FROM tabel ORDER BY _id DESC', [], querySuccess, queryError);
    }
    function errorDB(err) {
        alert("Error processing SQLnew: " + err);
    }
    function queryError(err) {
        alert("ERROR reading SQL" + err);
    }
    function querySuccess(tx, results) {
        callback(results.rows.item(0)._id + 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the error. Peraphs you have missed the () after now function?

Comment: and now() shouldn't be between `"`

Comment: I edited with the error message i get.